# Setting background image to a Header Cell

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to set a background image to my Header Cell table using this code:

```
Image esq = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(IMG1));
Cell cellh = new Cell();
cellh.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
cellh.setNextRenderer(new ImageBackgroundCellRenderer(cellh, esq)); 
table.addHeaderCell(cellh);
```

The issue is that only the first page shows the background image; the other ones are blank. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of making the questions clear, please attach the code of all the classes you are using, like `ImageBackgroundCellRenderer` you are referring to. This class is not a part of standard iText7 API.

I assume you are using the implementation which is similar to the following one:

```
private class ImageBackgroundCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    protected Image img;

    public ImageBackgroundCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, Image img) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        img.scaleToFit(getOccupiedAreaBBox().getWidth(), getOccupiedAreaBBox().getHeight());
        drawContext.getCanvas().addXObject(img.getXObject(), getOccupiedAreaBBox());
        super.draw(drawContext);
    }
}
```

This implementation might be found in samples and it solves the task which it is meant to solve for that sample.

In your case you are looking into reusing the cell. Custom renderers for elements that are reused or can be split across several pages must override/implement `getNextRenderer()` method, which creates a similar renderer that can be used for further processing (renderers cannot be reused on their own if they have been drawn already). The implementation would look like following:

```
@Override
public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
    return new ImageBackgroundCellRenderer((Cell) modelElement, img);
}
```

Overall, the following code should get you the desired result:

```
private class ImageBackgroundCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    protected Image img;

    public ImageBackgroundCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, Image img) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        img.scaleToFit(getOccupiedAreaBBox().getWidth(), getOccupiedAreaBBox().getHeight());
        drawContext.getCanvas().addXObject(img.getXObject(), getOccupiedAreaBBox());
        super.draw(drawContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new ImageBackgroundCellRenderer((Cell) modelElement, img);
    }
}
```

Comment: @WeslleyGuedes great! Please accept the answer then :)